# Nuget packages vs 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

Getting error in vs2015 with Nuget packages while restructuring solution. Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is.....

Any inputs are appreciated

Comment: What error message did you get when you enabled NuGet package restore?